# Fortran program doesn't update a variable's value properly

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to implement a Bisection method subroutine in Fortran to solve a computational science program and Fortran is doing some weird things. So the goal of the program is to find the solution of a transcendental equation for some parameter `e0` which is updated every step in a for loop and passed to the subroutine.

The problems are:

- `e0` is not updated as it should. The value of `e0` goes from 0.1799... to 0.8999... in one single iteration, while in theory it should take the program 9 interations to get there. Why is this happening?
- The print statements aren't printed as they should (see output below). We expect an "out 1" print, some "in" prints (printed when subroutine `f1` is called by subroutine `Bisection` some times), then "out 2" print (with the new e0 value), some "in" prints, etc. But we see the first "out 1" print, some "in" prints and then only "out" prints. Does this mean the subroutine `f1` is only called between "out 1" and "out 2"? (it should be called between every "out" print)

I have used Fortran77 for numerical solving for a couple years and never encountered something like this, but it's been nearly 6 months since I don't program anything so maybe I missed an important thing.

Code:

```
       program roots
       implicit none
       double precision A,B,eps,e0,e1
       integer i,niter
       external f1
       A = 1d-1
       B = 9d-1
       eps = 10d-6
       open(9,file='dades.dat',status='old')
       
       do i=1,9
       e0 = i*(B-A)/10 + A
c      Here is the first print. 'Out' meaning outside the subroutine
       print *, 'out', i, e0
       call Bisection(A,B,eps,f1,niter,e1,e0)
       write (9,'(2(f10.5))') e0,e1
       end do
       
       close(9)
       end program roots
       
       subroutine Bisection(A,B,eps,f,niter,xroot,e0)
       implicit none
              double precision A,B,eps,xroot,fuc,fua,e0
              integer niter,i
              niter = nint(log((B-A)/eps)/log(2.))+1
              
              do i=1,niter
                     xroot = (A+B)/2
c      Here the subroutine which uses e0 is called twice
                     call f(xroot,fuc,e0)
                     call f(A,fua,e0)
                     if (fuc .eq. 0) return
                     if (fuc*fua .lt. 0.) then
                            B = xroot
                     else
                            A = xroot
                     end if
              end do
              return
       end subroutine Bisection
       
       subroutine f1(x,f,e0)
       implicit none
       double precision x,f,e0
c      Here is the second print. 'In' meaning inside the subroutine
       print *, 'in', e0
       f = e0+1
       end subroutine f1
```

Output:

```
out           1  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 in  0.17999999999999999
 out           2  0.89999511718750003
 out           3  0.89999572753906254
 out           4  0.89999633789062505
 out           5  0.89999694824218746
 out           6  0.89999755859374997
 out           7  0.89999816894531248
 out           8  0.89999877929687500
 out           9  0.89999938964843751
```

Comment: I removed the [tag:fortran77] tag. The code is at least Fortran 90.

Comment: "This cannot be seen in this example" - if you us to look at this, please create an example which _does_ show the problem.

Comment: The solution to any problem with common blocks in new F90+ code is: don't use common blocks. There's no compelling reason to use blank common to solve this programming problem, which is likely to reduce the effort you may see in people helping you here. Please consider using "modern" programming constructs. (And calling subroutines `f` and `fun` etc will confuse many

Comment: You only set `e0` in the `out` do-loop before entering the subroutine.  `e0` is never updated in the subroutine.

Comment: @steve - `e0` is not intended to be changed inside the subroutine. The goal is to change `e0` every iteration before the subroutine, and the subroutine uses its value to calculate something

Comment: @francescalus - I have tried to rewrite the program so as not to use common blocks. I don't know if this is the way you had in mind. This change has not affected the output. By the way, since you mentioned it, is there a more efficient and clean way to achieve what I'm trying here? (I mean changing `e0`'s value in every iteration and using it inside a subroutine/function)

Comment: @JordiFuentes Error prone common blocks should not have been used for the last 25 years+ in new code. If you really must have global data (rarely a good idea) use modules which can do similar things to common but are less error prone. Best is through argument lists as you seem to have done in your update, but you should still really learn about modules and stick all subprograms in one - this is the modern, less error prone way; what you are doing at the moment is driving at 100 km/h without safety belts or brakes.

Comment: @IanBush - I've had a quick look at modules and they seem such a useful tool so thanks for that and your advices. I wasn't taught to use modules in my computational physics lectures, maybe because they showed us mainly Fortran77 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found out the issue after a deep look through the code. The problem is that variables `A` and `B` are both input and output because they are modified inside the subroutine. Because of that, when the subroutine is called the first time, it changes `A` and `B`'s value (which is different from the one set at the beginning of the code). The rest are issues originated by this.
The solution was to reset the values at the beginning each iteration as shown below:

```
       program roots
       implicit none
       double precision A,B,eps,e0,e1
       integer i,niter
       external f1
       eps = 10d-6
       open(9,file='dades.dat',status='old')
       
       do i=1,9
       A = 1d-1
       B = 9d-1
       e0 = i*(B-A)/10 + A
c      Here is the first print. 'Out' meaning outside the subroutine
       print *, 'out', i, e0
       call Bisection(A,B,eps,f1,niter,e1,e0)
       write (9,'(2(f10.5))') e0,e1
       end do
       
       close(9)
       end program roots
       
       subroutine Bisection(A,B,eps,f,niter,xroot,e0)
       implicit none
              double precision A,B,eps,xroot,fuc,fua,e0
              integer niter,i
              niter = nint(log((B-A)/eps)/log(2.))+1
              
              do i=1,niter
                     xroot = (A+B)/2
c      Here the subroutine which uses e0 is called twice
                     call f(xroot,fuc,e0)
                     call f(A,fua,e0)
                     if (fuc .eq. 0) return
                     if (fuc*fua .lt. 0.) then
                            B = xroot
                     else
                            A = xroot
                     end if
              end do
              return
       end subroutine Bisection
       
       subroutine f1(x,f,e0)
       implicit none
       double precision x,f,e0
c      Here is the second print. 'In' meaning inside the subroutine
       print *, 'in', e0
       f = e0+1
       end subroutine f1
```

Comment: If you really want the values of `A` and `B` be to be preserved, why not just making Bisection itself taking care of that by using local copies of those? Furthermore, I would add an interface for `f` inside `Bisection`, avoiding the need for `external`. There are also several things in the code making it rather Fortran 77 than anything else. Is there a special reason for this?

Comment: @Pap - Good point on making the local copies. It's such a simple concept I didn't come up with.  
When you say "add an interface for `f` inside `Bisection`" what do you exactly mean? Replacing `call f(xroot,fuc,e0)` by the actual calculation the subroutine does?  
The reason is that I was mainly taught Fortran77 and as I only use Fortran for sporadic numerical solving, I haven't invested more time in learning Fortran90.

Comment: Your code has several issues preventing me from posting a complete answer. To name a few:
(1) subroutine `f1` gets `x` and doesn't really use it at all.
(2) In `Bisection` you compare a real number with zero: `(fuc .eq. 0)`. This is a big "no-no" (in fact most compilers will at least issue a warning if you do that). Use something like `(abs(fuc) <= epsilon(1.))` instead.
(3) All variables in `f1` and `Bisection` are defined without any `intent` attribute, making hard to anyone, probably you too, to read the code and figure out what a procedure gets and what it returns.

Comment: @Pap - Yes you are right. (1) I simplified a lot the calculations `f1` does (compared to the actual code) just for the sake of simplicity and because using `e0 + 1` gave the same errors. In the actual function it does use `x`. (2) Yes I usually do that but as this is an old subroutine from when I started Fortran I completely forgot to change it. Thanks for the advice too! (3) I don't use the `intent` attribute because (I believe) it was not in Fortran77 and it's what they taught me, but maybe I should invest some time on learning it.